# My form's is_valid method returns false

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a form as below :

```
class CookDuty(forms.Form ):
    # cook = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cook = kwargs.pop('cook')
        super(CookDuty, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['duty'].choices = foods_for_cook(cook)
    duty = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
```

I have used it in a view as below, but `form.is_valid` returns false! I have checked `form.errors` and it's empty, `form.data` is empty, and form.is_bound is `False`.

```
def duty_list_cook(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c = Cook.objects.all()[0]
        form = CookDuty(cook=c)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            return render(request, 'employee/cook_duty.html', {'form':form})

    else:
        c = Cook.objects.all()[0]
        form = CookDuty(cook=c)
    return render (request, 'employee/cook_duty.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is a post request, you need to pass the POST data to the form.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    c = Cook.objects.all()[0]
    form = CookDuty(cook=c, data=request.POST)
```

Without the post data, the form is unbound, so will always be invalid.

See the docs on [bound and unbound forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms) for more info.

The second problem is that the `ChoiceField` field (used for selecting a single choice) isn't compatible with the `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget (used for selecting multiple choices). If you want to select multiple choices, then you need to use [`MultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) instead of `ChoiceField`.

```
duty = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
```

Comment: now it's bound but still it's not valid. when I print errors I get this : 
<ul class="errorlist"><li>duty<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. [&#39;pizza&#39;] is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: it's just like a checkbox . how can choices be invalid?? @Alasdair

Comment: That's a separate issue. I think the problem is that your widget doesn't match the field. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks. but I want to be able to select multiple choices. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to use a [MultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield).

Comment: but I want it to be like a check box beside each element. @DanielRoseman

Comment: Yes, that is what the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget is for.